# obtener resultado de un JsonResult en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5, post

Tengo una función "public JsonResult GetLibro"
que recibe datos de un ajax y los guarda lo que quisiera es que retornara un valor X de confirmación de que no hubo error en la validación y que los datos se guardaron pero no logro obtener el valor de mi Json en mi ajax este es mi codigo

Controlador:

```
public JsonResult GetLibro(int tipo,string descripcion,DateTime fechaInicial, DateTime FechaFin, int libro)
        {
            // aqui hago el guardado de datos 

            
            var result = new { Result = "Successed" };
            return Json(result);
        }
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("#btn").click(function () {
    
//Mando los datos a mi controlador
    $.ajax({
                url: "/GetLibro",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    tipo: tipo,
                    descripcion: descripcion,
                    fechaInicial: fecha,
                    FechaFin: FechaFin,
                    libro: libro,
                },
            })
    
    
    //pretendo recibir el resultado del controlador
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "/GetLibro",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.list[0]);
            }
        });
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: por que tienes una petición post, y otra get a la misma API, creo en la primera donde mandas el POST, deberías agregar la parte de sucess, para obtener el resultado

Comment: Hola Eduardo, Debería manejarlo Fuera de mi  `$("#btn").click(function () {}` ? y disculpa la pregunta como es la parte del Sucess que mencionas ??

Comment: tienes dos peticiones ajax, pero si en la primera envías los datos, es donde debes recibir la respuesta que se guardo. o no entiendo el por que dos peticiones ajax

Comment: mi idea era la primer funcion del ajax manda los datos y con la segunda digamos recibes y procesas pero por lo que me comentas desde la primer petición que get con el Succes puedo recibir la respuesta, estoy en lo correcto o aun estoy confundido?

Comment: Desde la primera petición que tienes con post, es donde debes recibir la respuesta a tu petición en especifico,  asi,  `$.ajax({
                url: "/GetLibro",
                type: "POST",
                data: {/*datos*/},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })`

Comment: Ya lo probé y funciono muy bien podrías ponerlo como respuesta para marcarla como correcta al final agregue también esto ,
            `,error: function () {
                alert("Fallo");
                console.log(data);
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso lo que estas realizando es generar dos peticiones a la misma ruta, pero en la primera es donde envías la información al servidor y entonces es donde deberías obtener el resultado.

En este caso tu petición quedaría como.

```
 $("#btn").click(function () {
    //Mando los datos a mi controlador
    $.ajax({
        url: "/GetLibro",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            tipo: tipo,
            descripcion: descripcion,
            fechaInicial: fecha,
            FechaFin: FechaFin,
            libro: libro,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Eduardo es justo la respuesta que necesitaba